# Опишите все случаи, когда константая ссылка может продлить жизнь объетка без имени, или же rvalue

Tags: c++

На данный момент я знаю лишь один способ:

```
const TYPE &ref = expression;
```

А также как и до какого момента работает продлевание жизни объекта без имени при помощи константной ссылки.

И почему не работает вот это как следует(вызывает undefined behaviour)

```
const int& f()
{ return 5; }
```

Comment: Что такое "способ"? Инициализация ссылки-параметра функции - это считается как другой "способ" или не считается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандарт C++17 говорит, что время жизни временного объекта продлевается до времени жизни ссылки, за исключением следующих случаев:

1. Время жизни временного объекта, созданного для инициализации ссылки-параметра при вызове функции, продлевается до конца полного выражения, содержащего этот вызов функции.
2. Время жизни временного объекта, созданного для инициализации ссылки в new-инициализаторе, продлевается до конца полного выражения, содержащего этот new-инициализатор.
3. Время жизни временного объекта, привязанного через `return` к возвращаемой из функции ссылке, не продлевается вообще.

Обратите внимание, что начиная с С++14 запрещается использовать временные объекты для инициализации ссылок в списке инициализации конструктора. Поэтому этот случай больше не упоминается среди вышеперечисленных исключений

```
struct S
{
  const int &r;
  S() : r(42) // Вопроса продления времени жизни нет, ибо 
    {}        // начиная с C++14 код просто некорректен
};
```

Что вы имеете в виду под "способами" из вашего вопроса не ясно. Можно заметить, что ссылку можно привязывать к подобъекту временного объекта и это продлит жизнь всего объекта

```
struct S { int x = 42; };
const int &r = S{}.x; // Продлевается время жизни всего `S{}`
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

---

P.S. Текущий черновик стандарта языка содержит еще более разветвленную спецификацию: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6

Comment: Я имел в виду слово "способ" как синоним слову "случай".

Comment: Небольшое пояснение по поводу третьего пункта, ибо именно по поводу него вопрос. В продлевании временного объекта, привязанного через return к возвращаемой из функции ссылке нет смысла. Когда вы пишете `Type foo(...) {Type result; ...; return result;}`, и в большинстве подобных случаев, компилятор проводит оптимизацию и не делает лишнего копирования при возврате временного объекта. Возврат проходит за константное время вне зависимости от размера результата. Поэтому возвращать из функции ссылку на временый объект нет смысла. Нужно возвращать по значению.